# Getting error "Failed: Fn is not a function" when try to automate e2e for a login page

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to automate and rum a simple register form but i am getting error saying "Failed: Fn is not a function". Below is my code

```
    describe('Locator testing by model', function(){

    it('automate user register form', function(){
        browser.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/registeration/#/login');
        element(by.model('Auth.user.name')).sendKeys('angular');
        element(by.model('Auth.user.password')).sendKeys('password');
        element(by.model('model[options.key]')).sendKeys('zafaque');
        element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
        browser.wait(3000);
    });
});
```

**below is the error detail**

```
    1) Locator testing by model automate user register form
  Message:
    Failed: fn is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: fn is not a function
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:716:14
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    From: Task: <anonymous>
        at pollCondition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2359:16)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2355:9
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1082:7)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2354:14
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
    From: Task: <anonymous wait>
        at ControlFlow.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2352:17)
        at Driver.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:712:29)
        at ProtractorBrowser.to.(anonymous function) [as wait] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:60:29)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zafaque/WebstormProjects/autotation/udemyProject/loginTest.js:12:17)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:23
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1082:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:80:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2820:25
    From: Task: Run it("automate user register form") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/zafaque/WebstormProjects/autotation/udemyProject/loginTest.js:6:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zafaque/WebstormProjects/autotation/udemyProject/loginTest.js:4:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `browser.wait()` incorrectly. Refer the official documentation for correct usage [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)

browser.wait() accepts params in the below order

> first argument is a condition which can be a function or a
>   webdriver.promise.Promise or a Expected Condition Second Argument is
>   the timeout

But you are passing timeout as the first argument. Incase you just wait a conditionless wait - Just use `browser.sleep(3000)`